# How to use Where clause when using XML in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I need to use a where clause in my query but I am not able to do it work.

I only want result WHERE attrpfd_attr_name LIKE 'ABC%' but I am not able to add this part of code to my query. Any thoughts ?

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF(
                 (
                     SELECT DISTINCT
                            ','+QUOTENAME(c.[attrpfd_attr_name])
                     FROM [dbo].[attrpfd_det] c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
                 SET @query = 'SELECT [attrpf_key1], '+@cols+'from (SELECT [attrpf_key1],
           [attrpfd_default_value_char] AS [amount],
           [attrpfd_attr_name] AS [category]
    FROM [dbo].[attrpf_mstr]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[attrpfd_det]
      ON attrpf_mstr.oid_attrpf_mstr = attrpfd_det.oid_attrpf_mstr
                 )x pivot (max(amount) for category in ('+@cols+')) p';
EXECUTE (@query);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without DDL it's hard to re-create this but you can add the filter to the JOIN via the ON clause like this:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF(
                 (
                     SELECT DISTINCT
                            ','+QUOTENAME(c.[attrpfd_attr_name])
                     FROM [dbo].[attrpfd_det] c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
                 SET @query = 'SELECT [attrpf_key1], '+@cols+'from (SELECT [attrpf_key1],
           [attrpfd_default_value_char] AS [amount],
           [attrpfd_attr_name] AS [category]
    FROM [dbo].[attrpf_mstr]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[attrpfd_det]
      ON attrpf_mstr.oid_attrpf_mstr = attrpfd_det.oid_attrpf_mstr AND attrpfd_attr_name LIKE ''ABC%''
                 )x pivot (max(amount) for category in ('+@cols+')) p';
```

Note the only change was to append

```
INNER JOIN [dbo].[attrpfd_det]
          ON attrpf_mstr.oid_attrpf_mstr = attrpfd_det.oid_attrpf_mstr
```

With:

```
AND attrpfd_attr_name LIKE ''ABC%''
```